# Why am I still getting 500 internal server error in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

**Please read this question before trying to down vote it. There are so many duplicates of the question and unfortunately none of them worked for me.**

I am using **CodeIgniter_2.1.4** version.

I have a simple registration form and I need to insert its data into the DB through an Ajax request. When there are no errors in the form:

```
POST path/index.php/controller/method 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have tried following solutions but I am still getting the error:

1. I have enabled CSFR protection in my `config.php` file: `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`
2. I am using `form_open()` and `form_close()` tags, because CI documentation says that it will automatically insert a hidden csrf field in forms if `form_open()` is used.

**Javascript**

```
$("#sign-up").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();                  


    alert($(this).serialize());
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        url:"<?php echo site_url('viewer/signup_process')?>",
        success:function(data){
            $("#update").html(data);
        }
    }) ;
});
```

**PHP code**

```
public function signup_process()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","Firstname","required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname","Lastname","required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("username","Username","required|max-length[10]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","Password","required|min-length[5]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("telephone","Telephone","required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email","email","required|valid_email");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("terms","Terms & Conditions","callback_agree_to_terms");

    if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
        //There are errors
        $data["title"]="Errors";
        $data["errors"]=  validation_errors();            
        $this->load->view("public/errors",$data);
    } else {
        $viewer=array(
            "firstname"=>  $this->input->post("firstname"),
            "lastname"=>  $this->input->post("lastname"),
            "username"=>  $this->input->post("username"),
            "password"=> $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post("password")),
            "telephone"=>  $this->input->post("telephone"),
            "email"=>  $this->input->post("email")
        );
        $create_result=  $this->Viewer_model->create_viewer($viewer);

        if($create_result){
            $data["message"]="Registration successful..Please sing in";
            $this->load->view("public/success",$data);
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: if you're making the request to your own site, turn up your `error_reporting` level and check your logs to see what the error actually is?

Comment: If you're just testing locally, try a try catch and echo the error you are getting.

Comment: @sevenseacat - I have made error_reporting = E_ALL in my php.ini file

Comment: @Jimmy - I tried my create statement in a try catch block, but no exception gets printed in catch block. And yes I am testing it locally

Comment: is your frontend and backend in different servers?

Comment: @Sandeep - All are in localhost

Comment: could u post ur php code as well?

Comment: @John - By default it was turned off and I had no idea about CSFR before getting this error. But 500 internal server error still appears even through csfr protection is turned off.

Comment: @Sandeep - PHP code was also added

Comment: @JohnSkoumbourdis i hope you have read the comments in that post too. and disabling CSRF is invitation to `Cross Site Requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answering my own questions

I could solve the problem by rewriting my index file using a htaccess.

**Steps**

1) Create a .htaccess file and save it in the **root** directory

**This is .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|css|js|img|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project_name/index.php/$1 [L]
```

*Comment - You may have different names for your css,js,img folders. You may have folders more than that or not. Adjust it accordingly.*

2) Go to application->config->config.php and make

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That is it.

Hope this will help a future reader

Answer (score 2):

Try by changing

```
method:"POST",
```

to

```
type:"POST",
```

Comment: sorry. It did not owrk

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the form validation module in the `autoload` file?

Else, you need to do this in the first line of your function:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Comment: It is not in the autoload file. But it is in the constructor of my controller